# some simple question in php

Tags: php, html

i have some simple question.
1-how can i change php pages in a specify points?
for example

```
if($flag)
//go to 1.php
else 
// go to 2.php
```

what i replace instead **go to ?.php**

2-

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="button" name ="submit" value="comfirm">
```

if i click on button index.php is execute
if there is any way  in particular condition that i want index.php is called

for example we have two text fields and a button user must fill both of text  and click on button until goes to next pages but if user fill one of text in must not go but in second way index.php must not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($flag) {
    header("Location:1.php");
    exit(0);
}
else {
    header("Location:2.php");
    exit(0);
}
```

For the second question you can either use Javascript (not all users have javascript enabled, so it's not guaranteed to work), and check the value of the fields, or hava a serversite check and redirect the user with `header`, as above.

Comment: This might be dangerous. Please add `exit(0)` after `header`.

Comment: ummmm this wont work at all. you forgot to wrap the statements with `{}`

Comment: @Neal Yes, forgot to add them when I added the exit statements. Have added them now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($flag) {
  //go to 1.php
  header("Location: 1.php");
  exit(0);
}
else  {
  //go to 2.php
  header("Location: 2.php");
  exit(0);
}
```

And for the second part you might want to use some client side script to double check the inputs and a server side script to double double check them

Comment: +1 Correct but it is better, as a good habit, to put a die() call after the header("Location: ...."), even if in this particular case it's not strictly needed. There are security concerns about it.

Comment: @mehdi: remember that headers can be ignored by browsers. For example if you use `header()` to redirect a user to a login page if he's not logged than if you don't use `exit(0)` he can easily ignore the header and go on with the rest of the page.

Comment: @Giacomo. Why do we need of exit(0) instead of exit()? Why you say it's better to use die() instead. The PHP Documentation don't mention any security problem and any differente at all between the 2.

Comment: @Charlie, `die` is just another way of writing `exit`, and `0` is the system code

Comment: `die` and `exit` are quite the same. However the PHP docs doesn't mention any security problem with `header()` because no-one said that an HTTP redirect performed with `header()` stops the execution of the script, so the security issue depends on what the script does after the `header()` call. The issue is not related to `header()` itself. Sometimes all of this is very dangerous, and I've ever seen some quite popular PHP tools that are screwing vulnerable because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use META refresh..

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=somewhere.php">
```

3 is the number in seconds before it redirects the viewer

Answer (score 1):

For `form` validations, you need to use **javascript**.

```
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function validateForm()
     {
         // Conditions to check whether the text box is empty or not.
     }

   </script>
 </head>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="button" name ="submit" value="comfirm" onsubmit = " return validateForm() ">
```

If `validateForm()` returns **true**, then only on button click it goes to `index.php`

Comment: you need to use some sort of serverside validation as well, js can be played with on the client side

Comment: @Neal - Please read the OP question. OP needs to stay on the current page itself when any element of the form is **empty**. What is the need to go to server side validation ?? Will be glad to know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: @Mahesh. yes, but you can validate on the server side with some ajax magic

Comment: @Neal - Last semester, I learnt **javascript** for my school project. So, it stayed fresh in my mind. I am not aware of **ajax**.

Comment: @Mahesh look it up :-) here is a tutorial i just found on google: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php

Comment: @Neal - Thanks for the link. Will learn it when I find time :)

Comment: @Neal - Yes, I see a lot of questions on ajax on SO. I am a C++ programming learner basically.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way because you have not to fight with the possible lost of the $_POST[]

```
if($flag)
   require '1.php';
else 
   require '2.php';
```